# Where does leading slash ("/") in java class loader getResource leads to?

Tags: java

I have a jar (foo.jar) with a file in it's root - 1.txt.

I tried to run the following command -

> MyTestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/1.txt");

The jar (foo.jar) was all I had in the classpath.

I expected this to work as the "/" is supposed to lead me to the root of the classpath/jar (according to other answers I've read in stackoverflow). This returns null.

But it seems that the leading "/" isn't working as expected for me.

I figured it out and it worked **without** the / -

> MyTestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("1.txt") -->
>   jar:file:/tmp/myjar.jar!/1.txt

What is the effect/purpose of leading "/" in getResouce?

Comment: There is a difference between `class.getResource()` (uses relative paths) and `class.getClassLoader().getResource()` (uses absolute paths)

Comment: You're just not supposed to have a leading slash. ClassLoader.getResource() doesn't expect one. Class.getResource() does, though, because without it, it looks for the resource in the same package as the class.

Comment: Are you using Java 9 modules?  They alter the way that Class::getResource delegates.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications! It's indeed a difference between the class and the classloader I've missed!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I expected this to work as the "/" is supposed to lead me to the root
>   of the classpath/jar (according to other answers I've read in
>   stackoverflow).

Leading slash works only for `class.getResource()` to override its default behavior. There is no leading slash concept for `class.getClassLoader().getResource()`, so it always returns `null`. IMO it should rather throw exception in that case, but fortunately this is solved in Guava's [`Resources`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Resources.html).

Comment: It is true that `class.getClassLoader().getResource()` should not have a leading slash in Java SE, but I found it works with a leading slash in Java EE. But I don't know why.